# Plotly in RStudio viewer

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly

I updated plotly to the newest version V2.0.3 because they say you can now have interactive plots in the viewer without hosting them on their website.  When I run a plot nothing shows up in the viewer, but if I click show in new window in the viewer it opens up in a webbrowser.  Any ideas why it won't show up directly in Rstudio viewer?  Their demo shows that it should be able to here:
https://plot.ly/r/offline/?campaign_id=open_source_dec2015&utm_source=Plotly+Community&utm_campaign=59ccfcd224-Open_Source_Announcement_General_Campaign12_9_2015&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_97ac8cf597-59ccfcd224-210656709

Comment: I just downloaded myself and ran in RStudio (not expecting it to show in the viewer) but it did and was interactive.

Comment: Thanks, what version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: I updated RStudio to newest version now it's working.  Thanks.